# JSONP response returns undefined unless used inside the JSONP callback function

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsonp

I am trying to get a JSONP response from Twitter and have the following code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            (function($, container) {

                container[$] = function(url){

                    url += '&callback=jsonp';

                    var scriptEl = document.createElement('script');

                    scriptEl.setAttribute('src', url);

                    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(scriptEl);

                }

                window.jsonp = function(response) {

                    return response;

                }

            })('$', this);
        </script>
        <script>
            var test = $('http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=jonathonoates');

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

If instead of `return response;` in the `window.jsonp` function, I were to stick an `alert(response)` I can see that I am getting a successful response from Twitter.

I would like to `return` that `response`, as in the `var test = $('http...');`, but `test` is undefined; the `response` is not being returned.

I am sure I'm looking at it silly, it's probably something to do with it being inside the closure?

I'd really appreciate you help with this!

Though, please, no jQuery etc. answers, as I'd like to learn how all this done by myself.

Thank you everyone!

Comment: Your anonymous function in the first script element defines two functions, and the one called `$` _doesn't return a value_. So saying `test = $('...');` is going to set test to undefined.

Comment: Thanks! I've tried moving the `jsonp` function inside the `$` function but now I get an error when wittier returns the JSONP response, telling me that the variable `json` cannot be found. Any more ideas?

Comment: This is a typical problem with asynchronous calls that rely on callbacks to get a response. The easiest thing is probably to move the code that wants to use the test variable inside the jsonp function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the behaviour of asynchronous calls, the callback function must be called after the JSONP has been retrieved from the source, in this case, Twitter.

The callback function should be passed as an argument along with the URL in the `$` function so it can be called from within the `jsonp` function, that should be a child of the `$` function.

```
                url += '&callback=jsonp';

                var scriptEl = document.createElement('script');

                scriptEl.setAttribute('src', url);

                head.appendChild(scriptEl);

                container.jsonp = function(response) {

                    return callback(response);

                }
```

and called like:

```
        function test(x) {
            alert(x);
        }

        $(test, 'http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=jonathonoates');
```